# Shake control for Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How would I use the accelerometer in WinPho7 to detect shaking the phone and have that trigger an event.  For example, to roll dice, you would shake the phone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are 3 solutions, each with code:

http://www.j2i.net/BlogEngine/post/2010/07/31/Detect-Shaking-Motion-on-Windows-Phone-7.aspx

http://blog.markarteaga.com/ShakeDetectionOnWindowsPhone7.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98492/Detect-Shaking-Motion-on-Windows-Phone-7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You would be after the [Accelerometer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.sensors.accelerometer.aspx) in the [Microsoft.Devices.Sensors namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.sensors.aspx).

While [this quick how-to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604984.aspx) is targeted at XNA game development, it gives a good example of the usage of the Accelerometer class.